# Is it possible to delete archived files in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have some archived test reports that I would like to delete from certain builds.    It would be good to do this from the jenkinsfile, but can do it manually too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

archived items are stored inside:

`C:\Users\<userID>\.jenkins\jobs\<jobName>\builds\<buildID>\archive`

You can remove them manually or write simple script to iterate over folders.
On Linux/Unix, user home will be different, but the rest of path will be the same.

Comment: I know the path to the archived items.  What script would I use to delete them?

Comment: I'd like to run the script either from the jenkins script console or from the jenkinsfile....

Comment: depending on your Jenkins host operating system you can use either sh (unix) or bat (windows)

Comment: sh "rm -R directory_to_remove"

Comment: bat "rd /s /q directory_to_remove"